# Determining the inital phase of a waveform

Tags: wave, waveform, graph

[image]

How could I determine the initial phase of the following sinusoids with these parameters only ?

from what I can see , I know that B is leading C since the crest is behind the Y axis .. Therefore , B = positive phase , C = negative phase. I also know that one cycle is 360 degree and consist of 4 divisions so 360/4 = 90 degree per division. but I still don't know how to calculate the initial phase of the waveform.

Another thing please is this the correct formula to know the normalised power basically (Power/sqrt(2))^2 and does it apply to any sinusoid ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

B leads C (or C lags B) because B crosses 0 on the same slope before C or B reaches a positive peak before C, etc.

To determine the phase angle with a scope, use the formula:
$$ \frac {d} {D} \times 360°$$
B has a period of 4 divisions or 360°. D = 4 divisions.  You could also use actual time, but the formula is a ratio.
[image]
Little d is where the second waveform crosses the x-axis on the same slope.  In this case d = 1.5 divisions.

$$ \frac {d} {D} \times 360° = \frac {1.5\ divisions} {4\ divisions} \times 360° = 135° $$

Phase Angle is 135°, which means B leads C by 135°.  At the same time C lags B by 135°.  Think of it like a queue.  First person always leads the second person.  2nd person is always behind the first.

Average power is:
$$ P = p(t) = v(t)\ i(t)$$

Normalized power assumes a load resistance of \$1\Omega \$.  This means current is numerically equal to voltage, so normalized power is:
$$ P_N = v(t)^2$$
$$ V_{RMS} = \sqrt {P_N}$$
$$ V_{MAX} = \sqrt {P_N}\ \sqrt {2}= \sqrt {2\ P_N}$$

which applies to any sinusoid (assuming a load resistance of \$1\Omega \$).

Comment: Great explanation, this is much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to begin by finding the frequency of each waveform. Wave B takes 50us to complete a cycle, so it has a frequency of 20kHz.

```
1 / 50us = 20kHz
```

Wave C also has a frequency of 20kHz. Once you have the frequency, you can find the phase by using the formula:

```
phase (deg) = 360 * f * delta_t
```

In this case, B leads C by about 18.75us, so

```
360 * 20kHz * 18.75us = 135 degrees
```

As far as the initial phase of each waveform, that is relative to what the waveform is, ie. sine or cosine.